# Why is the AttachEvent not fired?

Tags: gwt

I am having a `SimplePanel` (or `div`) which has the `contenteditable` attribute set to `true`. Inside this panel I have another *draggable* `div` which itself is not editable but lives inside the editable.

Having a content like

```
Text text <div draggable="true">DRAG</div> text text.
```

works for me so far. Dragging etc. works so far as expected. However, if the caret is next to the draggable `div` and the user hits <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> the draggable `div` gets removed too - and just to make it clear this is actually what I want - but the problem is that I need to know when this element gets removed to also remove its associated `DragStartHandler`.

The problem is that the `AttachEvent` appears not to be fired in this case - or I am doing it simply wrong. My `DragAndDropController` implements `AttachEvent.Handler` to qualify as handler. I am adding it for each draggable `Widget` but I never see any logging output as I would expect.

This is my current solution:

```java
public class DragAndDropController implements AttachEvent.Handler {

    private SimplePanel textarea;

    private Element currentlyDragged;

    public DragAndDropController(SimplePanel textarea) {        
        this.textarea = textarea;       
        // ...
    }

    public void addDraggable(Widget draggable) {

        DragStartHandler dragStartHandler = new DragStartHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
                GWT.log("Drag start for .." + draggable.getElement().getId());              
                currentlyDragged = draggable.getElement();              
                event.setData("text", draggable.getElement().getId());
                event.getDataTransfer().setData("text", draggable.getElement().getId());
            }           
        };

        // The handler I plan to remove ..
        final HandlerRegistration addBitlessDomHandler = this.textarea.addBitlessDomHandler(dragStartHandler, DragStartEvent.getType());

        draggable.addAttachHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
        GWT.log("DETACH");
    }

    // ..
}
```

I hope somebody can clarify. The devtool shows me that the affected `div` gets removed from the DOM tree (at least its HTML content disappears so I think I can make this assumption).

Answer (score 1):

None of your code shows the `Widget draggable` being added to a parent widget, so its unclear if the attach/detach wiring can be working as expected. If you simply call `element.appendChild(widget.getElement())`, this will correctly attach the dom element to the page, but will *not* inform the widget (or anything it contains or has subscribed to it) that it has been correctly attached.

In short, simply being visible (or not visible) is not enough to know that the widget was correctly attached/detached. Make sure the widget is attached to another widget (and so on, until a `RootPanel`).